# Working with Arrays and Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Looking to submit an array to firebase as a list of objects with integers as key names. I know that firebase does not support Arrays directly so was wondering how to do so. I am creating a list of items users add a users cart. so I am approaching it as such:

```
func addItemtoCart(item: String, completed: @escaping (_ completed: Bool) -> ()) {    Firebase_REference_Cart.child(userID).child("itemIDs").updateChildValues(["itemiD": itemID])
  completed(true)
}
```

I understand that this will not work because every time and item is added to the cart it will replace the item in under the "ItemId". I was looking to have something like this

```
CartITems: {
  0: "945495949856956",
  1: "9459469486895695"
  2: "J888568567857685"
}
```

If someone could please describe how to do this from A to Z in the most descriptive way possible it would help greatly. I am new to firebase and need a bit of guidance.

Comment: The Firebase documentation explicitly recommends against using arrays for such data structure. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#reading_and_writing_lists, which also includes sample code of how to add items to a list.

Answer (score 0):

First of all create model like:

```
struct Model {
var id: String
init(id: String) {
   self.id = id 
}}
```

Then make an instance of this model in your class: `var model = Model(id: "First Id")`
Then to push it to Firebase use:

```
func addInstance(model: Model) -> Completable {
    return Completable.create( subscribe: { completable in
            let reference = Database.database()
                .reference()
                .child("Models")
                .childByAutoId
            var model = model
            model.id = reference.key
            reference.setValue(model.dictionary)
            self.modelVariable.value.append(model)
            completable(.completed)
        }
        else {
            completable(.error(NSError(domain: "Sample", code: 403, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Server Error"])))
        }
        return Disposables.create()
    })
```